# Get dimensions and position of Ext JS child panel

Tags: extjs

I have an Ext JS panel container. Each time I click on a button, a child panel is created inside a panel container. I can drag–drop and resize the child panels anywhere in the container.

My issue is to get the width, height, and position of all the child panels and pass them to the server side when I click on a 'save' button. How this can be done? Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have created so far:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Panel, {

  // private
  initEvents: function () {
    if (this.draggable) {
      this.initDraggable();
    }
    this.resizer = new Ext.Resizable(this.el, {
      animate: true,
      duration: '.6',
      easing: 'backIn',
      handles: 'all', // handles:'s' gives vertical resizing only
      // minHeight: this.minHeight || 100,
      // minWidth:this.minWidth || 100,
      pinned: false,
      transparent:true
    });
    this.resizer.on('resize', this.onResizer, this);
  },

  onResizer: function (oResizable, iWidth, iHeight, e) {
    this.setHeight(iHeight);
    this.setWidth(iWidth);
    //alert(iHeight);
  }

});

var p = new Ext.Panel({
  border: false,
  layout: 'absolute',
  autoScroll: true,
  margins: '0 0 5 0',
  ref: 'containerPanel',
  resizable: true,
  title: 'Container Panel',

  buttons: [{
    text: 'Add Panel',
    handler: function () {
      var childPanelCount = w.containerPanel.items.length;
      var startYPosition = 10;
      startYPosition = startYPosition * childPanelCount;
      var childPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        draggable: dragMeToHeckAndBack,
        layout: 'fit',
        height: 100,
        title: 'New Panel ' + (childPanelCount + 1),
        resizable: true,
        width: 200,
        x: 10,
        y: startYPosition,
        tools: tools
      });
      w.containerPanel.add(childPanel);
      w.containerPanel.doLayout();
    }
  }, {
    text: 'save',
    handler: function () {}
  }]
});

var dragMeToHeckAndBack = {
  insertProxy: false,
  onDrag: function (e) {
    var pel = this.proxy.getEl();
    this.x = pel.getLeft(true);
    this.y = pel.getTop(true);
    var s = this.panel.getEl().shadow;
    if (s) {
      s.realign(this.x, this.y, pel.getWidth(), pel.getHeight());
    }
  },
  endDrag: function (e) {
    this.panel.el.setX(this.x);
    this.panel.el.setY(this.y);
  }
};

w = new Ext.Window({
  height: 600,
  autoScroll:true,
  layout: 'fit',
  resizable: false,
  width: 800,
  items: [p]
});

w.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

The getBox method of an [Ext.Panel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Panel) returns size and position:

```
var box = my_panel.getBox();

alert(
    'Box dimensions: '
    +' width='+ box.width
    +' height='+ box.height
    +' x='+ box.x
    +' y='+ box.y
);
```

Comment: how this can be applied in my code. i will be dragging/resizing some child panels and after that when i click the save button i need to get the current size and position of all child panels

Comment: You can any panel's children by iterating over the parent panel's 'items' property. If you are storing the parent in 'w.containerPanel' then you can pass a function to w.containerPanel.items.each and call getBox on each child panel that gets passed to it.

Comment: Now when i click on the button child panels are added one below the other inside the container panel. Each time i click on the button i want the child panels to be displayed at a predefined position say x:20,y:20. How this can be done?